# ASP.NET Chart not working on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, graph, web-config

I have been trying to make a web application and everything seems to be ok when I run it in my laptop but its just not working when I try uploading it into the server. I use a Godaddy windows server on .net 4. I tried tinkering with the web.config file but it doesnt seem to work.

This is how my temp image save location  in web.cofig looks life

```
  <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;" />
```

Am I missing something? Please help.

Answer (score 4):

if you are on shared hosting c:\TempImageFiles\ folder doesn't exists on server, and if somehow you can add that folder, asp.net application doesn't have rights to write outside of its root folder

Store it to the session

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=session;timeout=20;" />
```

look at

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deliant/archive/2008/12/02/managing-chart-generated-images-with-chart-image-handler.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still the problem seems to persist. Still getting a '500 internal server error' in godaddy.

Comment: Maybe for some other reason, you should set customErrors mode to off in web.config to see error details

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this same issue on my Godaddy 4GH shared hosting plan and thought I would share my solution.

1. Insert a chart control into Default.aspx

   The following code should pop up in your code behind file

   ```
   <%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
   Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" TagPrefix="asp" %>
   ```
2. Edit your web.config file

   I followed instructions on [this blog](http://mnarinsky.blogspot.com/2010/06/aspnet-40-chart-control-breaks-iis-70.html) and completely removed the httpHandlers node from my web.config file and overwrote the handlers node with the following code

   ```
   <handlers>
       <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
       <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
   path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler,
   System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
   </handlers>
   ```
3. Create a directory to store charts

   I created a new folder in the application root called Charts
4. Change chart control settings

   Update the ImageStorageMode and ImageLocation properties like this

   ```
   <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation" ImageLocation="~/Charts/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)">
       <series>
           <asp:Series Name="Series1">
           <Points>
           <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Greg" YValues="1" />
           </Points>
           </asp:Series>
       </series>
       <chartareas>
           <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
           </asp:ChartArea>
       </chartareas>
   </asp:Chart>
   ```
5. Publish to Godaddy
6. Edit file permissions on the Charts folder on the published site

   - Log into your Hosting Control Center
   - Click on FTP File Manager under Content
   - Navigate to your application root
   - Check the checkbox next to your Charts folder
   - Click on Permissions on the menu
   - Uncheck Inherit
   - Check Write (leave Read checked)
   - Click OK

Every time you republish your application you will have to repeat step 6.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Guessing that the `c:\TempImageFiles\` makes problems on your server

you can also try to set your storage mode to `storage=memory` istead of `storage=file`

check also this good documentation:
https://web.archive.org/web/20201205231110/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081909-1.aspx